# Avoid event capturing by another application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

Simply speaking, I have something like this

```
// Adds listener to capturing phase
document.addEventListener('focusin', event => event.stopPropagation(), true); 

document.querySelector('#my_div')
    .addEventListener('focusin', event => console.log('my logic'));
```

First event listener comes from the the application which I have no control over. It blocks all the focuses on the capturing phase (and it's also doing some logic which I omitted for the simplicity) and focuses on the modal window.

I embed my application (it's a content script of the Chrome extension) on the page and want to focus on the input of my ebedded element. It's not possible since all ***focusin*** event are captured by first element listener and it's not propagating it down to my element.

Is there any workaround to this problem? Note that I can't just fix the first listener since I have no control over this... Any ideas (and dirty hacks :) are highly appreciated.

Comment: But how focus propagates down to my_div?..

Comment: I misunderstood at first. Use event delegation like this: window.addEventListener('focusin', e=> e.target.id === 'my_div' && console.log('my logic'), true)

Comment: Ok, thank you, I’ll try this approach

Comment: @wOxxOm Indeed, it works! You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem

Your `focusin` listener is registered in the default second phase ("bubbling") since you didn't specify `true`. The site's `focusin` listener is registered with `true` in `addEventListener` so it runs in the first "capturing" phase (when the event descends from `window` to `document` and down to the focused element) and by using stopPropagation it stops further dispatching of the event so it never even reaches the default second phase where your listener waits.

#### Solution

As described above, the event in the capturing phase descends from `window`, so we can register a capturing listener on `window` to make it run before the site's `document` listener:

```js
window.addEventListener('focusin', e => {
  // For nested inputs the condition should be e.target.closest('#my_div')
  if (e.target.id === 'my_div') {
    console.log('my logic');
  }
}, true);
```